# Use files while seeding by bittorrent

Tags: bittorrent

Is it ok to use files in other programs while they being seeded at the same times by bit torrent? What if those files are dll's or exe's?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a strange question, but so far if multiple programmes just read a file (non exclusive) that should work without problems.

But I cannot tell you if your bittorrent client uses exclusiv read/write locks.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use files while seeding them assuming you're not modifying them. In order to mitigate problems with programs modifying files (like media players changing id3 tags for instance), uTorrent (and possibly other clients) hold files open in exclusive write mode to prevent other processes from modifying the files. If the program you're trying to open the files in is competent, it would presumably ignore failures to modify the files, and just read them (which is fine).